# What is the difference between "by the method "and "with the method "?

Tags: prepositions

Which  is gramatically correct to say? ;

I have gained 500 USD **by** this new method.
I have gained 500 USD **with**  this new method

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why the grammar sounds odd to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest :

'I've gained 500 USD **using** this new method'

**OR**

'I've gained 500 USD **by** **using** this new method'

This would sound a complete sentence, the other one mentioned is an incorrect sentence.

Comment: I really thank you

Comment: *With* does not strike me as odd either, though more informal than the neutral *using*.